# What is the best memory model in java for referencing Hash values?

Tags: java, hash, sha

I am reading a file which contains a list of sha encrypted Hashes.  I could just read them in memory as `List<String>`.

This is a very large list and a String maybe a very wasteful memory model...so I would like to figure out if there is a better way to store this list in memory.

For example, if it was a list of UUID strings, I would turn them into a `List<UUID>`.

Is there an equivalent for Hash?

---

Sorry - here is some background.  I'm doing some spark-map/reduce comparisons, and I'd like to make sure the hash's in memory are stored as efficiently as possible.

---

from the comments it sounds like I should store them in byte-array.  So that would mean converting the string to hash-object and then getting the byte array...

Comment: Assuming the hashes are base64-encoded strings, you can decode the strings and store each hash as a byte array. But you would need a really, really large number of hashes in the file to have memory problems. How many do you have? What is the size of the file Do you really need all the hashes in memory in the first place?

Comment: If they all have the same size (in bytes) you will probably perform better reading chunks of bytes instead.

Comment: @JBNizet what's the sense of storing hashes as byte arrays for referencing?

Comment: @Andremoniy I don't know what you mean by "for referencing". But a hash **is** a byte array (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest--). So storing it as a byte array sounds quite normal to me.

Comment: @JBNizet OP asks about model ... for referencing Hash values. I've concluded that he wants use them some how, may be as keys in Map.

Comment: @JBNizet and yes, I agree that encrypted hash generally is byte array

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `String` to a byte array simply by using the `String.getBytes()` method. Note that this returns the bytes that compose the string representation of the hash value, not the numeric value of the hash.

Instead, assuming your hash values are hexadecimal (base 16) encoded strings then you can use Google's `guava` library. It has a `Hashing` class with hashing utilities. It has a `HashCode` class that stores the hash value, e.g. in byte array (`BytesHashCode`). This class has a `fromString(string)` method to create a `HashCode` instance from which you can get the byte array / long / int representation of the actual value. This class is more-or-less equivalent to `UUID` in your example.

Comment: requires guava 15+